# How to design a speedometer gauge

Tags: html

I want to design a speedometer how do i do it using html5 
I am trying to write it's javascript for movement of needle,i need help with that logic also.

I tried with images it was working but i want to do it using coding and javascript.

Comment: Loads an loads of duplicates for this. The dup link I've given above includes an answer I gave with a gauge control written in 4 lines of JS code, using the Raphael library. It's really not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Making a speedometer using HTML5′s Canvas](http://geeksretreat.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/making-a-speedometer-using-html5s-canvas/)